# How to enable the GoalioRememberMe ( Remember Me feature for ZfcUser )

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

i`m trying to use https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe to get the "Remember Me" functionality for "ZfcUser" module for Zend Framework 2.

What i did to enable the plugin :

add 'GoalioRememberMe' modeule in:  /config/application.config.php
copy  in: /config/autoload/goaliorememberme.global.php
database: import schema.sql

no sign of this working 
( should a "remember me" checkbox appear on the login page ? - for me there isn't one)
( also no cookie with the name "remember_me" is created upon login )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the module with more documentation and providing an example login page that adds the checkbox. It overwrites the default ZfcUser login view and should be what you expect.

Hope that helps. If you have any other problems, just drop me a note, open an issue on github or whatever. Will try to answer as quick as possible.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the latest version. All appears to be ok, but i cannot see any checkbox in the login, dont know how to fix this. The install is the default with ZendSkeleton. Zend 2.1.4. Zfc-user "~0.1.1"